# Using underscore.js can reduce return an array?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, underscore.js

I'm trying to use reduce to return an array like so:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];
_.reduce(myArray, function (seed, item) { return seed.push(item);}, []);
```

I expect that it will produce an array just like myArray. Instead for the first item, seed is an array. Then for the second item, seed is a number. That causes an error and the third item is never reached.

Whats happening here?

Comment: Why do you need to use `reduce` like this? IF you need to clone an array you'wd better just `slice` it.

Comment: Seriously, this would be much better done as `myArray.slice()`

Comment: Well... It's example. I was actually trying to sort an array into groups which, yes, I know could be done with _.sortBy(). Functionally speaking map and reduce are the building blocks of the other more complicated list comprehension functions. So my question looks to understand why reduce was not returning a list, which was my first step to making a sort into groups using only reduce.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, `seed.push()` does not return the modified `seed`. Do the following, and it's right:

```
_.reduce(myArray, function (seed, item) { seed.push(item); return seed; }, []);
```